# Using Multi-Value Field in MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a MVF field (I am fully aware that this is not a best practice) and I need to create a query where the result looks like this:

```
PersonName  MVF_Opt_1   MVF_Opt_2   MVF_Opt_3
Tim         X           X           X
John                                X
Jake        X                       X
```

I tried using an expression for each one that looks like:

`MVF_Opt_1: IIf([Options].[Value] = 1,"X","")`

For each of the query columns I need, but this seems to only be working if the option in the expression happens to be the first value in the MVF.

I also have about 20 options that do not need to be listed in columns that I can disregard.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried a query which gives you one `[Options].[Value]` value per row and then feeding that to a cross tab query?

Comment: @HansUp I don't know enough about cross-tab queries to know where to start with that. MS Access specific SQL is somewhat new to me.

Comment: If your MS Office version includes Access, try the cross tab query wizard from the Access query designer.  Not only can the query designer help you construct a cross tab, but it will also help you with Access SQL syntax in general.

Comment: @HansUp That still doesn't allow me to only grab the columns I need (about 9 out of 35) and it doesn't allow me to just check-off if the row has that property.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working for me:

```sql
SELECT 
    mvfTest.PersonName, 
    IIf(DCount("*","mvfTest","PersonName=""" & [PersonName] & """ And Options.Value=""1""")=0,"","X") AS MVF_Opt_1,
    IIf(DCount("*","mvfTest","PersonName=""" & [PersonName] & """ And Options.Value=""2""")=0,"","X") AS MVF_Opt_2
FROM mvfTest;
```

Comment: I see the logic in how this would work, but I can't seem to get it to work on my end.

Comment: @Ethan You can download a working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/305666/mvfTest.zip)